# Amazon AWS App Runner - Can't Run Multiple Commands Under "Build command" Config?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-app-runner, aws-app-runner

I have the following in my `package.json` file:

```
"scripts": {
    "migrate": "knex migrate:latest"
},
```

Running `npm run migrate` works fine on my local machine.  When I try to add this command onto my existing build command:

[image: ![1](https://github.com/aws/apprunner-roadmap/assets/2464164/9717acb0-d1d6-42e2-8411-6204c15b484f)]

App Runner always gives an error and rolls back my change:

[image]

Does App Runner not support multiple build commands?

Comment: try this `npm install; npm run migrate`